# Can I use Html.Raw to set up a one letter code for card suits?

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

This is my cshtml file in WebMatrix (Razor syntax).  Is there some way to output the suit symbols using something really short like @S?  That is, I want to reduce @Html.Raw(S) to @S.  Can it be done somehow? I tried what I thought it might look like for the club suit, but it didn't work.

```
@{
    var S = "&spades;";
    var C = @"Html.Raw(""&clubs;"")";    
}

@Html.Raw(S)  <br />
@C 

<!-- output is 
♠ 
Html.Raw("&clubs;") 
-->
```

==============================================

Thanks @GSerg I get ♣ ♦ ♥ ♠ with your code:

```
@{
    var C = Html.Raw("&clubs;");  
    var D = Html.Raw("&diams;"); 
    var H = Html.Raw("&hearts;"); 
    var S = Html.Raw("&spades;"); 
}

@C  @D  @H  @S
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the ASCII code for it?

Comment: I'd just use the underlying characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var C = new MvcHtmlString("&clubs;");
```

On the other hand,

```
var C = Html.Raw("&clubs;");
```

does exactly the same.